# Cannot print a whole String

Tags: java

I am trying to get the standard input of int, double and String(same order) and then printing out the input in order(String, double and then int). Here is the code:

```
public static void main (String[] args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
    int intNum = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter a double: ");
    double doubleNum = scan.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter your string: "); 
    String str=scan.next();

    scan.close();
    System.out.println("Your string is: "+ str);          
    System.out.println("Your double is: "+ doubleNum);
    System.out.println("Your integer is: "+ intNum);
}
```

But when I am giving the input(for example):

```
Enter an integer:
88
Enter a double: 
11.1
Enter your string:
Hello World.
```

The output I am getting is:

```
Your string is: Hello
Your double is: 11.1 
Your integer is: 88
```

Here I am not getting the full string. Where am I going wrong?
I have tried 'nextLine' but it did not work.

Comment: Actually, you are not able to read the `String`. Use [`scan.nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) instead of [`scan.next(()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--)

Comment: Look at the Scanner javadoc - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: `nextLine()` does work, but you need to add an extra `nextLine` call after reading the double so it eats the newline behind that double. https://ideone.com/9d34xm

Comment: @AxelH when I am trying with  scan.nextLine(), it does not take input straight away gives me output with the empty string.

Comment: @TiiJ7 you are correct, it worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line - `String str = scan.next();`,
`.next()` function only take the first string value till it encounters a whitespace or a new line.

Instead use - `String str = scan.nextLine();` which takes the whole string line till it encounters a new line.